# Concatenate two fields and string in MS Access

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I want to concatenate two fields and in that 2 field should come in (). I am able to do the "(" but not able to get the closing brace

This is what I tried

```
[student].[Undergraduate Degree] & " (" & Year([student].[Graduation Date]) AS [Degree Recieved (Year)]
```

When I tried this, its showing error

```
[student].[Undergraduate Degree] & " (" & Year([student].[Graduation Date]) AS [Degree Recieved (Year)] & ")"
```

Tried few more combinations by keeping the braces at different places but none worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[student].[Undergraduate Degree] & " (" & 
Year([student].[Graduation Date]) & ")"   AS [Degree Recieved (Year)]
```